# Can I make my apple store app free with ads and give previous buyers ad free add-on?

Tags: app-store-connect

I am planning to make my app free with ads but include an option to remove ads. Can I automatically give the add-on to all the previous buyers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes and there's a few different ways to do it.  The path I followed was to release a small update that use `NSUserDefaults` to write a bool property when the app was installed.  Then, when I distributed the app update with the ads, I'd read if the user had that bool value.  If they did, they were a previous owner and I wouldn't show the ads.  If not, they were a new owner and got the ads.

You can do the same thing by having the app set a value on your own server (the app would call your server upon installation with a user-specific string).  This would do the same as using `NSUserDefaults` except the value is stored on your server and not the user's device.

There's a few examples online including how to store the bool value that will stay with the user even if they delete and reinstall the app.

Comment: I havent found any useful examples so far. Do you know of any that wont involve me using my own server?

Comment: Just use `NSUserDefaults` and set a bool value in the app delegate `didFinishLaunchingWithValues`.  I'll see if I can find an example but it's really very simple, just like saving any value to `NSUserDefaults`.

Comment: [Here's](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11174774/3487310) basic example.

Comment: If you don't store the association between user and app version on your server, you'll have trouble if the user wants to migrate to a new device.